# Overload swift method using same params but different external identifiers

Tags: swift, overloading

I have two methods in a protocol

```
func gameBoard(gameBoard : HSGameBoardViewController, canMovePieceFrom startIndex: NSIndexPath, to endIndex: NSIndexPath) -> Bool!
func gameBoard(gameBoard : HSGameBoardViewController, checkIfCellAtIndex startIndexPath: NSIndexPath, hasTheSameOwnerAsCellAt endIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool!
```

Both take the same three params and return the same type however have different external identifiers.

When implementing the protocol, Xcode makes this suggestion:

```
Method 'gameBoard(_:canMovePieceFrom:to:)' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'HSGameBoardViewControllerDelegate' ('gameBoard(_:checkIfCellAtIndex:hasTheSameOwnerAsCellAt:)')
```

**So i'm not sure why I can't do this?**

I've checked the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and they have methods that do what i'm trying to do. For example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

Comment: Did you implement both methods of the protocol?

Comment: Yes I have, I can post my implementation if that would help?

Comment: Is the compiler giving you a warning or an error?

Comment: The compiler is giving an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement both methods of protocol:

```
class HSGameBoardViewController{        
}

protocol HSGameBoardViewControllerDelegate {
    func gameBoard(gameBoard : HSGameBoardViewController, canMovePieceFrom startIndex: NSIndexPath, to endIndex: NSIndexPath) -> Bool!

    func gameBoard(gameBoard : HSGameBoardViewController, checkIfCellAtIndex startIndexPath: NSIndexPath, hasTheSameOwnerAsCellAt endIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool!
}

class Delegate: HSGameBoardViewControllerDelegate {
    func gameBoard(gameBoard: HSGameBoardViewController, canMovePieceFrom startIndex: NSIndexPath, to endIndex: NSIndexPath) -> Bool! {
       return false
    }

    func gameBoard(gameBoard : HSGameBoardViewController, checkIfCellAtIndex startIndexPath: NSIndexPath, hasTheSameOwnerAsCellAt endIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool! {
        return false
    }
}
```

Implementing only first method gives this error:

```
Method 'gameBoard(_:canMovePieceFrom:to:)' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'HSGameBoardViewControllerDelegate' ('gameBoard(_:checkIfCellAtIndex:hasTheSameOwnerAsCellAt:)')
```

But real error is that you did not fully implement protocol.

You can paste this example in playground and will see that there is no compiler error.

Comment: After uninstalling and re-installing Xcode, this now works. Thanks for your help!